Restriction on L'Hôpital's rule for oscillating functions as x approaches infinity
Suppose we have,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\text{x + sinx}}{\text{x + 2sinx}}$$
When my teacher gave me this problem I could solve it by taking out an $x$ from numerator and denominator:
$$\lim_{x\to ∞}\frac{\text{x(1 + sinx/x) }}{\text{x(1 + 2sinx/x)}}$$
And we have, $1$ as the answer.
However, our teacher pointed out that this question must not be done using L'Hôpital's rule. And said that the reason is out of our scope of understanding as of now.
Teacher also said that when we obtain a limit function after applying L'Hôpital's rule, and if we are required to conclude the answer in "the following way", we must avoid it and restart the problem with a different approach.
"The following way":
Use L'Hôpital's rule and get $$\lim_{x\to ∞}\frac{\text{1 + cosx}}{\text{1 + 2cosx}}$$
Here, cosx oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ as x tends to $∞$, i.e. it is finite but cannot be determined. The same with $2cosx$ in denominator. Thus this limit does not exist$(DNE)$.
This however is wrong and the right answer is 1 as obtained earlier.
The reason not to apply L'Hôpital's rule in such cases is beyond our understanding at present, he said.
But what is it really??
(I'm a student in school and do not know the rigorous limit calculus taught in colleges. Delta epsilon etc.)

If you know the statement of L'Hopital's theorem, you can check which condition is not fulfilled

What I've been taught is that if the functions in Numerator and Denomenator are differentiable and either in 0/0 or infinity/infinity indeterminant form, we can apply this rule

Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016), pages 248-249: one of the conditions is existence of limit $\frac{f'}{g'}$, which you have not.

You can't apply L'Hopital's theorem since the limit of the quotient of the derivatives does not exist. See the Wikipedia's page in the paragraph "Cases where theorem cannot be applied (Necessity of conditions)".
